# rails best_in_place POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, best-in-place

ruby 2, rails 4

I'm working on an app with inplace editing with /Gemfile

```
gem 'best_in_place', :git => 'https://github.com/aaronchi/best_in_place.git'
```

everything works fine to update a attribute. for Example

```
<td>
  <%= best_in_place_if signed_in?, 
    @entrance, :scene_id, 
    :type => :checkbox, 
    :collection => ["No", "Yes"], 
    :nil => "*" %>
</td>
```

creates a PUT request to update the boolean value.

Is there a way to create a POST request to create a new instance instead. Can i somehow integrate this in one of the given Options? What would be the syntax? Would be nice to be able to omit the _form partial and the new.html.erb completely this way.